# Platform Builder - File System File (.dat) - not working

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact, platform-builder

I am working on touch screen drivers from Touch Base.  I have the drivers working, but I am having a problem with the calibration utility.  It requires some external bitmap files and they have to be located in `\Application Data\updd`.  I have tried this:

```
root:-Directory("Application Data")
Directory("\Application Data"):-Directory("updd")
Directory("\Application Data\updd"):-File("calib_cr_32_1.bmp","\Windows\calib_cr_32_1.bmp")
Directory("\Application Data\updd"):-File("calib_cr_32_2.bmp","\Windows\calib_cr_32_2.bmp")
Directory("\Application Data\updd"):-File("calib_cr_32_3.bmp","\Windows\calib_cr_32_3.bmp")
```

I thought that maybe something was coming along and deleting the folder after the fact, so I tried this:

```
root:-Permdir("Application Data")
Directory("\Application Data"):-Permdir("updd")
Directory("\Application Data\updd"):-File("calib_cr_32_1.bmp","\Windows\calib_cr_32_1.bmp")
Directory("\Application Data\updd"):-File("calib_cr_32_2.bmp","\Windows\calib_cr_32_2.bmp")
Directory("\Application Data\updd"):-File("calib_cr_32_3.bmp","\Windows\calib_cr_32_3.bmp")
```

In either case, the Application Data directory exists, but nothing is in it.  I tried looking at the initobj.dat file and I don't see anything else that is using Application Data.  For the configuration file I was able to put it here:

```
root:-Directory("touch")
Directory("\touch"):-File("tbupdd.ini","\Windows\tbupdd.ini.orig")
```

That works just fine.  The touch directory is created and that file is copied.  So it seems to be something specific to Application Data.  Does anyone have any ideas on what my problem could be?

This is Windows Embedded Compact 7.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, your code has no problem and should work fine. Can you test it by changing **Application Data** to **ApplicationData** and try?

Comment: I am basically doing that, but I changed it to "touch" instead.